# How do i remove all the files that contain a certain string in their name?

Tags: windows, ms-dos, wildcards

How do i remove str files with names containing "fr" in them ("text.fr.str") using DOS command?
I tried "DEL *.fr.str". Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and delete file by file one at a time.

```sh
for %i in ("*.fr.str")do del /q /f /a: "%~i"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Del /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)